# Cómo hacer un UPDATE a todas las columnas de una tabla de mas de 60 columnas?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema con un SP que realiza una actualización de todas las columnas de una tabla, el Update busca los registros vacíos y los actualiza con valor "NULL".

El problema es que la tabla es de más de 60 columnas y para no hacer el UPDATE columna por columna, utilicé el siguiente Query Dinámico:

```
    DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(4000) ='', @query NVARCHAR(4000) =''

            SELECT @col= @col+
                c.NAME+' = CASE WHEN '+c.NAME+' like ''""'' OR '+c.NAME+' like ''''  THEN NULL ELSE '+c.NAME +' END,
            '
            FROM  sys.columns c
            JOIN sys.tables t
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            WHERE t.name = 'personas'
            and c.name not like 'UserId'
            and c.name in ('FirstName',
                            'LastName',
                            'BirthDate',
                            'Gender',
                            'Email',
                            'Identification',--... hasta la columna 30

            SET @col =LEFT(@col,LEN(@col)-6)

            SET @query = 'update personas 
            SET 
                '
            SET @query = @query+@col

            SET @query = REPLACE(@query, 'Authorization', '[Authorization]')


            --PRINT @query
            EXEC sp_executesql  @query
```

Y posterior a ese primer query hice este segundo query dinámico:

```
        set @col =''
            set @query=''

            SELECT @col= @col+
                c.NAME+' = CASE WHEN '+c.NAME+' like ''""'' OR '+c.NAME+' like ''''  THEN NULL ELSE '+c.NAME +' END,
            '
            FROM  sys.columns c
            JOIN sys.tables t
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            WHERE t.name = 'personas'
            and c.name not like 'UserId'
            and c.name not in ('FirstName',
                            'LastName',
                            'BirthDate',
                            'Gender',
                            'Email',
                            'Identification', --... hasta la columna 30

            SET @col =LEFT(@col,LEN(@col)-6)

            SET @query = 'update personas 
            SET 
                '
            SET @query = @query+@col

            SET @query = REPLACE(@query, 'Authorization', '[Authorization]')

            --PRINT @query
            EXEC sp_executesql  @query
```

Como ven, es un poco enredado y complejo, pero fue la mejor forma que encontré para solucionar este problema y contener la posibilidad que en un futuro esta tabla me llegue con otras columnas y que este UPDATE se actualice automáticamente.

En los detalles verán que tuve que usar los dos query, para partir el proceso en dos porque la cadena NVARCHAR(4000) no era suficiente para el UPDATE que se genera el código entonces a través del parámetro in y no in partí el proceso en dos.

La pregunta entonces que me permito hacer a la comunidad es preguntarles si existe otra forma más eficiente de programar este UPDATE en el SP de forma tal que la tabla que me llegue que de entrada se que van a ser mas de 60 columnas, pueda actualizar todas las columnas, buscando registros vacíos y reemplazándoos por el valor "NULL"

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Entiendo que cuando hablas de eficiencia hablas de escribir menos código. Respuesta rápida NO y agrego: lo que estás haciendo no es una buena práctica y es eventualmente ineficiente en cuanto a performance. Puedes ayudarte de un query dinámico para generar la primera vez la clausula de update de la tabla con las 60 columnas, y no tener que escribir una por una, cuando cambie la tabla, editas la query y agregas la nueva columna ¿cuántas veces puede cambiar una tabla?

Comment: Usar querys dinámicos reduce muchas veces la capacidad de optimización que pueda hacer el motor, ni hablar de eventuales problemas de inyección de SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría es generar una tabla temporal, y hacer un recorrido de cada campo para actualizar el valor.

Entonces si tienes mas campos simplemente lo haría automático.

```
DECLARE @TABLA AS VARCHAR(100) = 'personas'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMPCAMPOS
CREATE TABLE #TEMPCAMPOS ( ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), CAMPO VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO  #TEMPCAMPOS
SELECT c.NAME
FROM  sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types Y ON c.system_type_id =y.system_type_id
WHERE T.TYPE='U' 
    AND  t.name = @TABLA
    and  y.name in('varchar','nvarchar')

DECLARE @MAXID AS INTEGER = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #TEMPCAMPOS)
DECLARE @ID AS INTEGER = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #TEMPCAMPOS)
DECLARE @CAMPO AS VARCHAR(100), @STRSQL AS VARCHAR(100);
WHILE @ID <= @MAXID
BEGIN
    SET @CAMPO =  (SELECT CAMPO FROM #TEMPCAMPOS WHERE ID=@ID)
    SET @STRSQL = 'UPDATE  ' + @TABLA + ' SET [' + @CAMPO + '] = NULL  WHERE [' + @CAMPO + '] = ''""'' OR [' + @CAMPO + ']='''''
    PRINT (@STRSQL);
    EXEC (@STRSQL);
    SET @ID =@ID + 1;
END
```

Comment: Eduardo, Gracias por tu respuesta... realmente solucionó mi requerimiento y de forma elegante... ahora lo que haré es convertirlo en un Procedure para que reciba una tabla X y realice esta limpieza. Mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con la misma idea que tu tienes, pero un poco más ajustada. Te expongo el escenario que planteas:

```
Drop table if exists dbo.nuevaTabla;
Create table nuevaTabla 
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
col1 varchar(100),
col2 varchar(100),
col3 varchar(100),
col4 varchar(100),
col5 varchar(100),
col6 varchar(100),
col7 varchar(100),
col8 varchar(100),
col9 varchar(100)
)
GO
Insert into dbo.nuevaTabla 
(Col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9)
values
('','','','','','6','""','','');
GO
```

Lo primero que hay que tener en cuenta, es que exec sp_executeSql no esta restringido a un nvarchar(4000). Según la doc, puedes utilizar un nvarchar(max)

[exec sp_executeSql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Por otro lado la manera más efectiva de obtener las columnas y quitar todas las que no te cogen es utilizar informationSchema.Columns y restringir por la posición (solo si todas las bases de datos, tienen las mismas columnas en la misma posición).

[image: Resultado]

```
DECLARE @col Varchar(8000) ='', @query NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'';
 Select @col = Concat(@col
                ,QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
                ,'='
                ,' NULLIF(TRIM(''""'' FROM '
                ,QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),'),'
                ,''''''
                ,'), '
                ,CHAR(13)) 
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns t
    Where t.TABLE_NAME = N'nuevaTabla'
        and t.ORDINAL_POSITION > 1;
        -- en tu caso, será la columna 30

--Elimino el cambio de linea, y la última coma
SET @COL = SUBSTRING(@COL,1,LEN(@COL)-3);

SET @QUERY = N'UPDATE N SET 
'+@COL + N' 
FROM dbo.NuevaTabla N
;';
Print @query
exec sp_executeSql @query
```

Como puedes ver por el código, con la función NullIf que nos retorna null cuando las dos expresiones a comparar son iguales, y con la función Trim, que nos elimina los caracteres especificados, podemos devolver null cuando sea "" o cuando sea ''.

```
    (1 fila afectada) 
UPDATE N SET  [col1]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col1]),''),  [col2]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col2]),''),  [col3]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col3]),''),  [col4]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col4]),''),  [col5]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col5]),''),  [col6]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col6]),''),  [col7]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col7]),''),  [col8]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col8]),''),  [col9]= NULLIF(TRIM('""' FROM [col9]),'')  FROM dbo.NuevaTabla N ;
```

[image: Resultado]

[Trim](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[NullIf](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)